# React Native - Unable to resolve module

Tags: android, react-native

Before adding this question , I have checked previous answers. Unfortunately I didn't find any fit to this. I'm a beginner in React Native and I'm following a tutorial. I'm getting this error.

[image]

index.android.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

const App = () =>(
    <Header/>
);


AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums' , ()=>App);
```

header.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
  return <Text> Albums ! </Text>;
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: just uninstall and Rebuild App

Comment: Here you've said that the file is Header.js, but your import is lowercase h header. Typo here or in your project?

Comment: @MattyK14 - Sorry it was my mistake in typing here. It's actually header.js. I corrected here

Answer (score 0):

```
//import lib
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,View} from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';

// create the component
const App = () => {
  return (
              <Header />
    );
};
// render the component
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListItem', () => App);
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = (props) => {
  return(
     <Text > Albums ! </Text>
 );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Getting the same errror :(

Comment: Check both console

Comment: This error is because of you are  defining wrong path for Header Component or because of you are misspell a name of that component

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a wrong path please correct this

```
import Header from './src/components/Header';
```

With

```
import Header from '../src/components/Header';
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to pass in the `props` from your `index.android.js` to your `header.js`.In your original code,you set `const Header = (props) => {` in your header.js,but you didn't pass the `props` in your index file.

```
    //import lib
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,View} from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';

// create the component
const App = () => {
  return (
       <Header headerText={'Albums'} />
    );
};
// render the component
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListItem', () => App);
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = (props) => {
  return(
     <Text > {props.headerText} </Text>
 );
};
export default Header;
```